# How to add a hiding delay to Full CSS Dropdown Vertical Menu

Tags: javascript, css, delay, settimeout, drop-down-menu

I have this script for my CSS Vertical Menu:

```
//Nested Side Bar Menu (Mar 20th, 09)
//By Dynamic Drive: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/

var menuids=["sidebarmenu1"] //Enter id(s) of each Side Bar Menu's main UL, separated by commas

function initsidebarmenu(){
for (var i=0; i<menuids.length; i++){
  var ultags=document.getElementById(menuids[i]).getElementsByTagName("ul")
    for (var t=0; t<ultags.length; t++){
    ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className+=" subfolderstyle"
  if (ultags[t].parentNode.parentNode.id==menuids[i]) //if this is a first level submenu
   ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t].parentNode.offsetWidth+"px" //dynamically position first level submenus to be width of main menu item
  else //else if this is a sub level submenu (ul)
    ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t-1].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].offsetWidth+"px" //position menu to the right of menu item that activated it
    ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover=function(){
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="block"
    }
    ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout=function(){
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="none"
    }
    }
  for (var t=ultags.length-1; t>-1; t--){ //loop through all sub menus again, and use "display:none" to hide menus (to prevent possible page scrollbars
  ultags[t].style.visibility="visible"
  ultags[t].style.display="none"
  }
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", initsidebarmenu, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", initsidebarmenu)
```

Where can I use timeout() to delay de menu from hiding right away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script:

```
//Nested Side Bar Menu (Mar 20th, 09)
//By Dynamic Drive: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/

var menuids=["sidebarmenu1"] //Enter id(s) of each Side Bar Menu's main UL, separated by commas
var defaultDelay = 0; //ms

function initsidebarmenu(){
    for (var i=0; i<menuids.length; i++){
        var ultags=document.getElementById(menuids[i]).getElementsByTagName("ul");
        for (var t=0; t<ultags.length; t++){
            ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className+=" subfolderstyle";
            if (ultags[t].parentNode.parentNode.id==menuids[i]){ //if this is a first level submenu
                ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t].parentNode.offsetWidth+"px"; //dynamically position first level submenus to be width of main menu item
            } else{ //else if this is a sub level submenu (ul)
                ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t-1].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].offsetWidth+"px"; //position menu to the right of menu item that activated it
            }
            ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover=function(){
                var elem = this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
                if (elem){
                    if (elem.timer){
                        clearTimeout(elem.timer);
                    }
                    elem.timer=0;
                    elem.style.display="block";
                }
            }
            ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout=function(){
                var elem = this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
                if (elem){
                    var delay = defaultDelay;
                    if (elem.parentNode && elem.parentNode.parentNode && elem.parentNode.parentNode.className){
                        var match = /submenu-delay-([0-9]*)/i.exec(elem.parentNode.parentNode.className);
                        delay = (match && (match.length > 1)) ? match[1] : defaultDelay;
                    }
                    elem.timer=setTimeout(function(){
                        elem.style.display="none";
                    }, delay);
                }
            };
        }
        for (var t=ultags.length-1; t>-1; t--){ //loop through all sub menus again, and use "display:none" to hide menus (to prevent possible page scrollbars
        ultags[t].style.visibility="visible"
        ultags[t].style.display="none"
        }
    }
}

    if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", initsidebarmenu, false)
    else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", initsidebarmenu)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebarmenu">
<ul id="sidebarmenu1" class='submenu-delay-1000'>
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Folder 1</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Folder 2</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Folder 2.1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Folder 2.1.1</a>
        <ul class='submenu-delay-5000'>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.1.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Folder 2.1.1.3</a>]
            <ul >
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.1.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.1.3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this piece of code is making the menu to stay open all the time, it is not giving a delay before closing it. If I move the mouse out of the menu it doesn't close.

Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the effects you are describing, changed the code to be "safer". I did test with Firefox 3.6.17, Chrome 13.0.782.14 and IE 9.0.8112.16421(Quirks mode, IE7, IE8, IE9) all on windows 7. In which browser are you testing? Btw, changed some of the coding style(sorry).

Comment: I use Firefox 4.01, Chrome 12.0.742.91, IE8, IE9 and Safari 5.0.5. I tried the new piece of code you sent and it works, the only issue is when you move over a third level menu, it overlaps for a few seconds while the first opened menu hides. Is it possible to control the hiding just for the second level menu? and the third level just hides immediately? Or something else, I'm just thinking. But anyway, thanks a lot for your help on this man.

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks a lot Prusse, the script is working great. And it is excellent to be able to control every level's hiding time individually. Thanks again.